# mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python

I am trying to using the program fbruteforcer.py. I compiled it and it seems to work but not at all.

The following works:

```
./wpbruteforcer.py -t www.pillolhacking.net -u admin -w wordlist
```

But when I try to change the destination site and the name of the user, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fbruteforcer.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "./fbruteforcer.py", line 247, in main
    releaser()
  File "./fbruteforcer.py", line 183, in releaser
    bruteforce(word.replace("\n",""))
  File "./fbruteforcer.py", line 152, in bruteforce
    opensite = br.open(targetsite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in 
_mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I tried to search for a solution, but all I could find was [this post](http://osdir.com/ml/python.wwwsearch.general/2007-06/msg00021.html).

Please someone help me idk what to do. Maybe I must download another mechanize package?

Comment: what was the new destination you tried? is it actually accessible from a browser?

Comment: I was trying to insert the site **www.google.com**, **www.facebook.com**, **www.virgilio.it** but it doesnt work with those, i have an account on them so i know my pwd anyway it doesnt work.

P.S . maybe its can help, **i`m using ubuntu 12.04**

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do but googling a bit I see that this script is for Wordpress sites and it probably appends paths to the url that don't exist in the sites you say you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the first thing it does is try to connect to:

```
"http://www."+target+"/wp-login.php"
```

Where target is what you inputed.

```
http://www.google.com/wp-login.php does not exist, hence the 404
```